# How to validate a List of nested Objects in nest.js

Tags: arrays, validation, nestjs

I want to validate a list of nested Object @ the request:

```
export class Room {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  name: string;

  @ApiProperty({ type: [RoomMate] })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsArray()
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  roomMates: RoomMate[];
}
```

The documation linked at nest.js (https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validating-arrays) only talks about nested Objects, but not about a List of nested objects

If I execute the code above it says:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "message": [
    "0.an unknown value was passed to the validate function"
  ],
  "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

If I delete "@ValidateNested({ each: true })" it won't be validated (you could pass eg Cats & Dogs instead of RoomMates)

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

For `@ValidateNested`, I've found you need to specify an `@Type` as well:

```
  @ApiProperty({ type: [RoomMate] })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsArray()
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => RoomMate)
  roomMates: RoomMate[];
```

The class-validator README examples assume you're working with classes, and there's [a section on validating plain objects](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validating-plain-objects). [This example in the class-transformer README](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#working-with-nested-objects) shows using `@Type()` to specify the type of a nested object.

Also, makes sure `RoomMate` is a class and not just a TypeScript interface.

See [this issue](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/198) on class-validator for some more information.

Comment: Thank you VEEEERRRY much .... yes now it works. There are totaly 3 modules which contains a decorator "Type" 

I've choosen this:
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';

... and now it works!